# How can I write to file descriptor 3 via pwsh on linux

Tags: powershell, ubuntu, powershell-core

I'm using `pwsh` on linux to run some specific powershell modules.

I want to output the data received to file descriptor 3. I want data on file descriptor 3 as Powershell doesn't respect the convention that stdout is data and stderr is logging. I want file descriptor 3 to serve as our "data" file descriptor.

End goal is to be able to do something like this as we wrap this powershell call in Python and we'll redirect the file descriptor 3 data ourselves

`pwsh -f script.ps1 3>data`

Comment: Is `pwsh -f script.ps1 3>data` not working?

Comment: I'm not sure how to output to file descriptor 3 with PowerShell. Sorry if my question isn't clear! I know that Streams (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2)  are not equivalent to file descriptors. But what would we use? 

I'm looking for something like Write-FileDescriptor3 "Hi FD3"

Comment: `pwsh -f script.ps1 >3` ?

Comment: No, that outputs stdout into a file called 3. https://gist.github.com/visch/e3105ee6125a03066e69bd45eb440f34

Comment: @js2010 I uploaded an example of doing this with python here https://gist.github.com/visch/e3105ee6125a03066e69bd45eb440f34

Comment: I tried 1>&3, but it says bad file descriptor.  I guess it depends on the shell.

Comment: It seems like it's possible somehow?  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42728/what-does-31-12-23-do-in-a-script

Comment: @js2010 I don't think it's possible from powershell which is my issue :/

Comment: @visch It looks like you're running it from bash no?  There's no way to tell.

Comment: @js2010 yes, but that doesn't change the fact that the powershell process can't send data to filedescriptor3. yes I could redirect stdout to filedescriptor3 via bash but that's not what I'm after

Comment: Oh I see, the shell is python.  How about `bash -c 'pwsh script.ps1 1>&3'`? (Or something like 1>&3 in python.)

Comment: This goes to what powershell considers 3:  `write-warning hi`

Comment: @js2010 yes that's a Stream I mentioned it quickly in another comment above https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2 it's not a file descriptor :/

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_output_streams?view=powershell-7.2 does a better job explaining Streams

Comment: That's true.  From bash this goes to a file, so it goes to 1 in bash:  `pwsh -c 'write-warning hi' > file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell has *no* built-in way to output to streams *other* than stdout (`1`) and stderr (`2`) (more on that below.

*Conceivably*, you can roll your own output behavior with .NET API and/or P/Invoke calls, but that would be cumbersome.

However, this may not be required:

- While it is true that - unfortunately - PowerShell *by default* sends output from *all* its [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) to *stdout* - see [GitHub issue #7989](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7989) -  you *can* redirect PowerShell error-stream to *stderr*, *if you apply a `2>` redirection on the caller's side*.

The following call, e.g. from `bash`, demonstrates this:

```bash
# Prints just 'hi', because the error-stream output was
# redirected to stderr thanks to 2>, and due to targeting /dev/null, suppressed.
pwsh -noprofile -c '"hi"; Write-Error no!' 2>/dev/null
```

The downside is that if you want to print the stderr output too, you must capture it *in a file* and print it *afterwards*, which means that it  (a) won't appear at the time it is being produced and (b) therefore won't be properly interleaved with any *stdout* output.

---

As an aside:

- The current behavior of the PowerShell CLI (as of v7.2.x) is unfortunate not only with respect to how output streams are mapped, but also because it loads [profile files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) *by default*.
- There was talk about providing a separate CLI to address the latter problem, in the context of which the stream-mapping behavior could be fixed too, but nothing has happened so far: see [GitHub issue #8072](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8072).